# How to get real request when using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm wondering how to get the "real" requested URL, when using mod_Rewrite. There are several rewrite rules in my htaccess-file for caching-purposes: First there is a check, if a cache-file is existent. If so, the request will be rewritten to the cache-file. Otherwise the request will be rewritten to a php-script, which creates this cache-file.

But I suspect, the rules doesn't match like I want them to. Is there a possibility to trace the "real" requests to see, which URL was requested by the client and which file is requested in the background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a foggy memory... I think you might be able to set a variable using mod_rewrite which can later be used.  Or, there is a builtin variable representing the original request.  Sorry, cannot remember clearly, but suggest you read the manual (good long read, but helpful)

Answer (score 0):

You may want the `%{THE_REQUEST}` special variable. The [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) say this:

> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional headers sent by the browser. This value has not been unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables below.

So if someone enters http://your-domain/path/file.html into their browser and your webserver rewrites **/path/file.html** into something entirely different, the %{THE_REQUEST} variable will still be `GET /path/file.html HTTP/1.1`, or something similar.

As for what the request finally got rewritten to, you can turn on logging for rewrite to see what it is:

```
    RewriteLog /some-path/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 9
```

This would go in your virtual host config and only be used for debugging purposes. The rewrite.log file will contain details on the rewriting process and what the final URI is.

Comment: RewriteLog sounds good, but as far as I know, there is no possibility to get this running via .htaccess. Unfortunatley I don't have access to httpd.conf or other configuration files.